How to apply Poincare's inequality to the following formula
We know that a generalized Poincare inequality holds: for $p>n$, there is a constant depending only on $p$ and $n$ so that
\begin{equation}
\sup _{s, y \in B_r}|u(x)-u(y)| \leq C r\left(\int\hspace{-1.05em}-_{B_r}|D u|^p d x\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, how to apply the above Poincare's inequality to $u(x)-u(x_{0})-Du(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})$ to obtain the following inquality for $x\in B_{r}(x_{0})$
$$
\left|u(x)-u\left(x_0\right)-D u\left(x_0\right) \cdot\left(x-x_0\right)\right| \leq C r\left(\int\hspace{-1.05em}-_{B_r}(x_{0})\left|D u(x)-D u\left(x_0\right)\right|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\;?
$$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Apply the first inequality to the function $v(x) := u(x) - Du(x_0)(x-x_0)$
